# Charging a binary tree

Tags: tree, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to charge a binary tree in an ascendent form from a file of Integers, but it doesn't works.

```
program trees;

type 
        fl = file of Integer
    ;   ltree = ^puntTree
    ;   puntTree = record
                val : Integer
            ;   big : ltree
            ; low : ltree
        end
    ;

procedure openFile ( var iFile: fl; name: String; var error: Boolean );
    begin
        error := false;
        assign ( iFile, name );
        {$I-}
            reset ( iFile );
        {$I+}   
        if ( ioResult <> 0 ) then
            error := true;
    end;


procedure loadTree ( var tree: ltree; var iFile: fl; var principalNode: ltree; position: Integer );
    var val
                :Integer
        ;   node
                :ltree
        ;
    begin
        if ( tree = nil ) then
            begin
                seek ( iFile, position );
                read ( iFile, val );
                new ( tree );
                tree^.val := val;
                tree^.low := nil;
                tree^.big := nil;
            end;

        if not eof ( iFile ) then
            begin
                read ( iFile, val );

                node := principalNode;

                while ( node <> nil ) do
                    if ( node^.val < val ) then
                        node := node^.big
                    else
                        node := node^.low;

                cargartree ( node, iFile, principalNode, ( position + 1 ) );
            end;
    end;

procedure printTree ( tree: ltree );
    begin
        if ( tree <> nil ) then
            begin
                printTree ( tree^.low );
                writeln ( tree^.val, ' - ' );
                printTree ( tree^.big );
            end;
    end;

var 
        tree
    ,   principalNode
            :ltree
    ;   iFile
            :fl
    ;   fileName
            :String
    ;   error
            :Boolean
    ;

begin
    readln ( fileName );
    abrirfile ( iFile, fileName, error );
    if not error then
        loadTree ( tree, principalNode, iFile, 0 );
    printTree(principalNode);
end.
```

This is the code.

The file have 9 elements:

```
1 5 9 20 58 95 1 3 8
```

But when I print the tree, the console shows only:

```
1 -
```

There's a way to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: You code style is an interesting art, however (at least for me) very badly readable.

Comment: I'm studying systems engineering and I adopted this form of writing the code because when we make exams with pens and sheets, this is the best way to read the code (for me).

Comment: Where is the definition of 'cargartree'? I think it would be much easier to debug if you separate the tree handling part from the file handling part - have the main part of the program read the numbers from the file then pass those numbers to the tree building procedure. LoadTree should be a recursive procedure.

Comment: This can't be the original code if you're calling `abrirfile` but declaring `openFile`, and the parameters to the call `loadTree` are not in the correct order.

Comment: On the first call to `openFile`, you are passing in pointers that have not been initialized (I don't know if free pascal automatically sets them to `nil` or whether they're undefined).

Comment: @No'amNewman, "cargar" means "to load", so the function is really calling itself. But some of the function names have been translated in copying of the function to stackoverflow.

Comment: If your file is `file of Integer` then when you read the file it will read it as "raw integers", not read ASCII and interpret it as integers, which is what your file is. So the `seek` logic won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to imagine what the code given is supposed to do as opposed to what it actually does, the primary error is that you are passing 'principalnode' to 'printtree'; you should be passing 'tree' to this procedure.